# Handling several Azure Functions with same named DLL

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We are building a Azure Function App where we have 5 different functions with their separate bin folders (one for each function), but each bin contains a private assembly (dll) (although the code used to create that assembly is different) with the same name, as far as I understand as they all share the same Azure Function App domain at runtime which dll is loaded depends on the runtime and may cause the other functions to fail

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for a single Function App, all your functions will run in the same app domain (for C#/F#/Node/Powershell). Therefore, you can't have multiple functions running concurrently that each load a different assembly with the same name.

Some of the supported languages are "out of proc" (e.g. BAT). When those functions are executed, they run in a separate process. However the drawback there are that a new process is spawned for each invocation, so you'd only want to use that for non high-throughput scenarios.

Comment: Another thing to consider then is, what if we have different versions of the same nuget package being used in single Function App, by different functions